# How to remove broken Wiki entries in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

We created automated release notes to be generated in AzureDevops wiki using Release tasks in AzureDevops

[image]

[image]

However during testing some incorrect entries were created in AzureDevops wiki.

It is impossible to remove them using GUI or azure devops CLI.

1. First issue

Error about inocrrect path is shown for a page (both from UI and CLI)

[image]

2. Second issue

Broken folder. There is no ,,More..." option available from UI. Azure devops CLI gives no option to remove folders.

[image]

If i Click it we can see

[image]

Is there any other way ?

Regards.

Comment: Are you able to open the wiki you created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my friends managed to solve this.

The underlying issue it seems is that UI in the backEnd doesn't save paths with spaces but rather with '-' chars.

So if we create on UI folder 'some items' it will be saved in backEnd as 'some-items'

Since we used automation to try to create articles under that folder and used the version with no '-' it somehow broke the wikis UI.

**Solution:**

In case if some entries are broken we can use git clone to clone wiki repo and fix it (delete incorrect folders, files) on windows or linux (we used linux since there were some additional problems on windows). Then after fixes are applied commit push it back up.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Azure Devops CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/add-edit-wiki?view=azure-devops&tabs=azure-devops-cli#delete-wiki-page) or [REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/wikis/delete?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to see if this works.

**Azure Devops CLI:**

To delete a wiki page, enter the `az devops wiki page delete` command.

```
az devops wiki page delete --path
                           --wiki
                           [--comment]
                           [--project]
                           [--subscription]
                           [--yes]
```

**REST api:**

Deletes the wiki corresponding to the wiki name or Id provided.

```
DELETE https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}?api-version=5.1
```

Comment: I tried azure devops CLI. It shows the same exact error as from GUI. ,,Wiki page ‘/...’ could not be found. Ensure that the path of the page is correct and the page exists.". Still the page is shown in UI. Also there is no command for removing folders.

Comment: How does your wiki page look like? Could you please provide an example so that I can reproduce your issue?

Comment: I edited the article. Shown both cases of broken pages. Can't seem to remove them from GUI or Azure devops CLI

Comment: How did you create the incorrect entries? Could you please provide an example so that I can reproduce your issue? Meantime, could you capture fiddler trace to see whether there is useful information.

Comment: Like I mentioned incorrect entries were created using Azure Devops Release tasks. I added example image. If the path was somehow incorrect it did create a broken entry. If you would pick ,,Copy page path" in wiki on the folder and then append something to create a subpage in the release task a broken entry should be created.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce your issue. When I try entering`[release](/releasepage)/platform.md` in the `Name of the file/page`, it will create a tree structure entry. Then I can delete from the bottom. It seems there is something messed in your account. Have you tried API? How's the result?